# Series for inverse of Euler's harmonic number integral $H_x=\int_0^1\frac{1-t^x}{1-t}dt$

Tags: power-series, inverse-function, harmonic-numbers

I'm looking to find a series for the inverse of Euler's analytic continuation of the harmonic numbers

$$H_x=\int_0^1\frac{1-t^x}{1-t}dt$$

From what I've seen, this integral is equal to the power series

$$-\sum_{k=1}^\infty {x\choose k}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}$$

> Using these facts, is it possible to find a series for $g(x)$, acting as the inverse of $H_x$, such that $g(H_x)=x$?

I'm unsure if there is a general process to get the inverse of a power series of known coefficients. [This website](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2018/02/24/invert-power-series/) seems to lead the general idea but I'm not certain if this is applicable here.